# Can't get SharedPreferences from Activity to BroadcastReceiver started after reboot

Tags: android, variables, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

I created an activity which starts an alarm based on user input values (hour, minute) which are saved using SharedPreferences in the same activity. What I want do is to start that alarm after phone reboot, but I need to get those values saved using SharedPreferences in the activity to the BroadcastReceiver which filters on BOOT_COMPLETED action. I tried to do it like this but what I get is default values "0":

```
package com.salivan.calmmanager;

import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class AlarmReceiverBC extends BroadcastReceiver {
int hour = 0;
int min = 0;

public AlarmReceiverBC() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        SharedPreferences savedData = context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_SAVED_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //here I try to get
        //the SharedPreferences but I think that the context object is wrong because it's sent by system and not by the activity where my values are... 
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        this.hour = savedData.getInt("HOUR", 0);
        this.min = savedData.getInt("MIN", 0);

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, this.hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, this.min);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intentForReceiver = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentForReceiver, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Do you have `android:process` values in your manifest?

Comment: No. Please more explanation.

Comment: I fixed my problem myself. Where SharedPreferences savedData = context.getSharedPreferences(String name, ...); I had to put the value of the string PREFS_SAVED_DATA which I have written in the activity but not the string name. That was my dumb mistake.